# NullPointerException trying to Autowire Service in Java Application (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am writing a Java Application that is going to be using Spring, Hibernate and more its going to be packaged in a Jar and run from the command like.

My main class looks like the following right now:

```
public class App
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);


    @Autowired
    private static MemberInquiryService memberInquiryService;


    public static void main(String[] args )
    {
        logger.info("Starting Inquiry Batch Process");

        int pendingRecords = memberInquiryService.getPendingRecordCount();

        logger.info("Current Number Of Pendinig Records (" + pendingRecords + ")");

        logger.info("Ending Inquiry Batch Process");
    }
}
```

and in the getPendingRecordCount I am just return "10" for testing:

```
public int getPendingRecordCount()
    {


        return 10;
    };
```

Why would I be getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.XXXX.inquirybatch.app.App.main(App.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Also here is my DatabaseConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages= { "org.xxxx.inquirybatch", "org.xxxx.core" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig  {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource()  {

        String serverType = env.getProperty("server.type");

        try {

            if(serverType.equalsIgnoreCase("tomcat"))
            {
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource ds = new com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource();

                ds.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("database.driver"));
                ds.setUser(env.getProperty("database.user"));
                ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
                ds.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));

                return ds;
            }
            else
            {
                Context ctx = new InitialContext();
                return (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/mySQLDB");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                  logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
     }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory()
    {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.xxxx.inquirybatch.model", "org.xxxx.core.model" } );

        try {
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }


        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", env.getProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));




        hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", env.getProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode"));

        //Audit History flags
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager()
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        htm.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        htm.afterPropertiesSet();
        return htm;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the spring config.xml?

Comment: I am not using Spring Config.XML.. I am using JavaConfig..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the main class to..

```
public static void main(String[] args )
    {
        logger.info("Starting Inquiry Batch Process");

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        MemberInquiryService memberInquiryService = (MemberInquiryService) context.getBean("memberInquiryService");

        int pendingRecords = memberInquiryService.getPendingRecordCount();

        logger.info("Current Number Of Pendinig Records (" + pendingRecords + ")");

        logger.info("Ending Inquiry Batch Process");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring never injects static fields. And it only inject objects that are retrieved from the application context, or are themselves injected into other objects.

You're not even creating an application context in your program, so Spring doesn't play any role in this program.

I suggest to read [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-introduction).

Comment: so how would I fix this, please keep in mind I am using JavaConfig

Comment: It seems you got it finally, so reading the documentation probably helped. Not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the memberInquiryService from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

For example :-

```
ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring config.xml");
MmberInquiryService memberInquiryService = context.getBean("memberInquiryService ");
```

basically in your code snippet MemberInquiryService is not spring managed as you are not getting from spring container. Also you need to declare MmberInquiryService  entry in  spring config.xml